# Counterpart of 'SwiftKey' for Windows?

Tags: keyboard

I am using SwiftKey for my Android phone. It is awesome because of its nice auto-complete function.

I am looking for a Windows app that does the same thing.
When I am typing something, I hope the software recommends a word or a phrase based on my typing history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows10+ has it built-in.  For hardware keyboard

- Open **Settings**
- Type in **Typing** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Scroll down to **Hardware Keyboard**
- Enable **Show text suggestions as I type**
- Enable **Autocorrect misspelled words as I type** if you want this too.

[image: Screenshot]